# 'num_of_cmt' is 4 instead of 2. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 4 tables:

users (id, name, email);

```
id  |   name    | email
1   |   ABC     | abc@gmail.com
2   |   XYZ     | xyz@gmail.com
3   |   AAA     | aaa@yahoo.com
```

papers(id, title, content, created_by)

```
id  |   title               |   content             |   created_by
1   |   This is title 1     |   This is content 1   |   1
2   |   This is title 2     |   This is content 2   |   1
3   |   This is title 3     |   This is content 3   |   3
4   |   This is title 4     |   This is content 4   |   1
5   |   This is title 5     |   This is content 5   |   3
6   |   This is title 6     |   This is content 6   |   2
```

rating(id, paperId, star)

```
id  |   paperId     |   star
1   |   1           |   2
2   |   2           |   4
3   |   3           |   4
4   |   2           |   2
5   |   1           |   3
```

comments(id, paperId, msg)

```
id  |   paperId     |   msg
1   |   1           |   abcd
2   |   2           |   xxxx
3   |   2           |   yyyy
4   |   3           |   zzzz
5   |   1           |   tttt
6   |   4           |   kkkk
```

I want to get fields: papers.id, papers.title, papers.content, users.name,
    AVG(rating.star), COUNT(comments.msg)

And I execute a query like:

```
SELECT papers.id, papers.title, papers.content, users.name,
AVG(rating.star) AS avg_star , COUNT(comments.msg) AS num_of_cmt 
FROM papers
JOIN users ON users.id = papers.created_by
LEFT JOIN rating ON rating.paperId = papers.id
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.paperId = papers.id    
WHERE papers.id = 1
```

Then result is false at "num_of_cmt" field:

```
id  title               content            name     avg_star    num_of_cmt
1   This is title 1     This is content 1   ABC     2.5000       4
```

Above, 'num_of_cmt' is 4 instead of 2. Why?

Comment: The same way that you left join one table, except that you do it four times.  If you want us to solve your actual problem, put that in your title instead of asking how to join four tables (because that's a *very different question* than the one you're asking in the body of your post).

Comment: If you display ALL the fields you'll see repeated rows. This is because Joins are cross-product operations. You could use nested queries and group-by's to get the correct counts instead of multiples of the actual count.

Comment: Group rating and comments by paperId, aggregate then join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ratings` and `comments` have multiple rows for `paperid = 1`.  So, joining the tables yields four results, with the following ids:

```
ratings    comments
   1          1
   1          5
   5          1
   5          5
```

Hence, the count is 4.  You can fix the count by doing `count(distinct comments.id)`.  However, the average is going to be off.

One way to fix this problem is by aggregating `ratings` and `comments` in subqueries.